# How can I use JDBC connection pooling in Jetty 8?

Tags: java, jdbc, jetty, jndi, connection-pooling

I used Tomcat's JDBC connection pool previously where it [could be easily configured in Java](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html#Plain_Ol%27_Java).

Now I use Jetty 8.

How can I use JDBC connection pooling in Jetty? I looked [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JNDI_Datasource) however I don't know where to put those XML snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure all JNDI resources in a jetty.xml file or in a WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml file, or a context XML file. For more information, see JNDI.

You will also need to add the pool implementation jar file to the classpath.